# Bootstrap Modal not performing the operation required

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, spring-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I am using Bootstrap Modals in a jsp page, the pop up shows but nothing happens when you click on the "Yes" button. It should delete the relevant entry from the table, but it is not working. It is working without using Bootstrap Modal which means that servlet end is fine, but I need to add the "Are you sure you want to delete pop up". Not sure what is wrong in this code as everything seems to look ok.

Address to the servlet should be the following

```
     ${pageContext.request.contextPath}/subject/delete/{subjectId}
```

Here is the code

JSP Page:

```
       <div class="table-responsive" >
          <table width="100%" id="example" class="cell-border example" cellspacing="0" style="font-size: 14px ; margin-left: 10px; text-align: center; border: 1px solid black;">

                                            <tr style="background-color: white; color: black; border: 1px solid black; text-align: center">
                                                <th style="text-align: center">Sr.</th>
                                                <th style="text-align: center">Code</th>
                                                <th style="text-align: center">Title</th>
                                                <th style="text-align: center">Status</th>
                                                <th style="text-align: center">Actions</th>
                                            </tr>

                                        <c:forEach items="${subjects}" var="subject" varStatus="counter">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="font-size: 14px ; border: 1px solid black; background-color: white">${counter.count}</td>
                                                <td style="font-size: 14px ; border: 1px solid black; background-color: white">${subject.subjectCode}</td>
                                                <td style="font-size: 14px ; border: 1px solid black; background-color: white">${subject.subjectName}</td>
                                                <td style="font-size: 14px ; border: 1px solid black; background-color: white">${subject.status}</td>
                                                <td style="font-size: 14px ; border: 1px solid black; background-color: white">
                                                    <a style="" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/subject/edit/${subject.subjectId}" title="Edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o edit"></i></a> &nbsp; &nbsp;
                                                    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="color: red; font-weight: bold" <%--href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/subject/delete/--%> onclick="changeDeleteId(${subject.subjectId})"><i class="fa fa-trash-o delet"></i></a>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </c:forEach>
                                    </table>
                                </div>

 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content my-popup">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Delete</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">  Are You Sure to Delete? </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="delete_no" href="">Yes</a>  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

  <script>
    function changeDeleteId(x) {

        var str = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/subject/delete/" + x;
        $("#delete_no").attr("href",str);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried writing an AJAX call to your spring controller that deletes the table entry on button click? Then you can dismiss the modal and show a message based on the controller's response.

Comment: @plasticpie Not very familiar with AJAX, how would I be able to do that?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/